# how to create finder with service-builder liferay without finder-column

Tags: liferay, liferay-service-builder

how to create method getAll without  finder-column 
in service.xml write

because i need get all data in province table without input parameter.

when run liferay:build-service accrued exception:
 The content of element type "finder" is incomplete, it must match "(finder-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the Entity (read table) is called Foo.
I think you could add the `getAll` method manually to the `FooLocalServiceImpl` and rerun service-builder. That should do the trick.

Something like:

```
public List<Foo> getAll() {
    return FooLocalServiceUtil.get(QueryUtil.AllPos, QueryUtil.AllPos);
}
```